# Login failed for user (SQL Server) via VBA (Excel) Macro

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel, adodb

I'm creating a macro in an Excel spreadsheet that will connect to an instance of SQL server using SQL Server Authentication.  This is a recycled function I've written previously that I know works.  I suspect it's either the way I've constructed the connection string for the SQL authentication, or the way the user is configured (although I have successfully logged into the server through SSMS with the user account so I know the account works).

```
Public Function GetConnection(ServerLocation As String, db As String) As ADODB.Connection
Dim ServerName As String, cn As ADODB.Connection, un As String, pw As String

un = "MyUser"
pw = "MyPassword"

ServerName = "MyServer"

If cn Is Nothing Then
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    cn.ConnectionString = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & ServerName & ";Database=" & db & ";UID='" & un & "';Pwd=" & pw & ";"
    cn.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    cn.Open
```

When I run the macro I get

> Login Failed for user "MyUser"

at the `cn.Open` line.

I've checked that remote logins are allowed, and both SQL Server and Windows Authentication modes are enabled.  I've also recreated the user account just in case.

Is there an issue with the connection string or am I missing something on the server?

Many thanks!

Comment: Try with the SQL Server Native Client 11.0. That old SQL Server driver is, well, very old... confirm they exist in your ODBC admin first of course.

Comment: Here is what I usually use: `Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=" & ServerName & "; Initial Catalog=" &  db & "; Integrated Security=SSPI;`

Comment: @JacobH the reason I'm using the old old driver is because I've had some users without the native client driver on their machines. This one seemed to be availavle on all if not most.  Is there a more up to date driver that is likely to be on the our network machines?

Comment: @braX my understanding is that using SSPI forces windows authentication, which is not what I'm after.  Unless I'm wrong?

Comment: You dont have to use Windows Authentication, that's just what I use. You can specifiy a username and password if you want.

Comment: What is the error message in the sql server log?

Comment: @UGP the error message is `Login failed for user ''MaintAppUser''. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided.`, suggesting that the user name is being passed incorrectly in the connection string (since I can log in via SSMS with MaintAppUser)?

Comment: i dont see anything wrong in the connection string though. have you tried using `sa` or any other user?

Comment: Thanks for suggesting viewing the Logs, @UGP.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution: the single quotes around the `UID` are not required.  I spotted these after viewing the Log and noticing the way the user name was formatted.  Without the additional single quotes the connection is successful and my procedure executes successfully.

My final connection string looks like this:

```
cn.ConnectionString = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & ServerName & ";Database=" & db & ";UID=" & un & ";Pwd=" & pw & ";"
```